# Method chaining with async/await in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, typescript2.0

I have a situation where I need to call an async method on the result of an async method.

```
class Parent {
  constructor(private child: Child) { }

  private getChild(): Promise<Child> {
    return Promise.resolve(this.child);
  }

  async getResult(): Promise<Child> {
     return await this.getChild()
  }
}

class Child {
  getText(): Promise<string> {
    return Promise.resolve('text');
  }
}

let child = new Child();
let container = new Parent(child);

let printText = async () => {
  await (await container.getResult()).getText();
}

printText();
```

Is there a good way to avoid the need to double await? I think I'd like to just do `await container.getChild().getText();`. What's the right way to make an API in TypeScript that will allow me to chain methods that return promises and then wait for the result with a single await?

EDIT: To clarify, this is more of an API design question. Is there a better pattern for doing what I'm trying to do (call an async method on an object returned by an async method)? Even if it means doing something totally different?

Comment: To chain promises without using `await`, use [`.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

Comment: Just a quick note, your anonymous function discards the text without doing anything. I'm not sure if you intended that or not. You can replace the outer `await` with a `return` and that might do what you want.

Comment: You're awaiting two things, so why would you hope to be able to write a single await? If you were using promises, you'd have to use `then` twice as well. You can write `const result = await container.getResult(); await result.getText();`.

Comment: Replace the outer `await` with `return` :-)

Comment: The `await container.getChild().getText();` syntax is not possible when `getChild` returns a promise, as promises don't have a `getText` method. End of story.

Comment: Yeah, the example is a little simplistic. I guess I'm asking an API design question. Is there a way to design my API better so that users won't need the double await? Even if it means changing the structure of my example drastically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to design my API better so that users won't need the double await? Even if it means changing the structure of my example drastically.

You must not make `getResult` asynchronous, it needs to return a `Result` instance right away so that further methods can be called on it. Your example is a bit weird since `getChild` doesn't really need to be asynchronous at all. But lets assume it is, and does some important.

You then could write

```
class Parent {
  private async getChild(): Promise<Child> {
    … // whatever
  }

  getResult(): Result {
     return new Result(this.getChild())
  }
}
class Result {
  constructor(p: Child) {
    this.promise = p;
  }
  async getText(): Promise<string> {
    return (await this.promise).getText();
  }
}
```

Now you can call `parent.getResult().getText()` directly. Basically, `Result` acts as a proxy wrapper around the `Child` class that does both the awaits. Maybe in your actual architecture you can even avoid the `this.promise` and do the child and text accesses in one step.

However, usually this is not worth it. Just let your caller `await` each step.

Comment: Right, my example is contrived and doesn't really need to be asynchronous. Thanks, this is what I was looking for! I agree, just making people explicitly `await` is probably better, I just wanted to explore my options.