# Javascript: Async Function Chaining in Class with return this

Tags: javascript, function, class, method-chaining

I am trying to do function chaining in a Javascript class by returning this after each method, but somehow, it does not work..:

```
let sql = require('mssql');
let {logger} = require('../utils/logger');
let config = require('config');
//mssql_stellenanzeigen_config = config.get('stellenanzeigen');
mssql_doublettencheckui_config = config.get('doublettencheckui');


class MSSQLConnectionObject {
    constructor(configuration) {
        this.configuration = configuration; 
        this.connection = undefined;    
        this.requestObject = undefined;  
    }

    async build() {
        let pool;
        try {
            pool = await new sql.ConnectionPool(this.configuration).connect(); 
            console.log("Connection established!: ", pool);
        } catch(e) {
            logger.error("No SQL Database config or wrong config. Can't establish connection to MSSQL Server. " + e);
        }    
        this.requestObject = await new sql.Request(pool);

        return this;
    }

    static async connect(config) {        
        let pool;
        try {
            pool = await new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect(); 
            console.log("Connection established!: ", pool);
        } catch(e) {
            logger.error("No SQL Database config or wrong config. Can't establish connection to MSSQL Server. " + e);
        }    
        this.requestObject = await new sql.Request(pool);
        return this;
    }

    async getBuchungsquelle() {
        const query = `SELECT * FROM buchungsquelle`;
        return await this.requestObject.query(query).then((result) => console.log(result)).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}

module.exports = {
    MSSQLConnectionObject
}

   let query= `select * from buchungsquelle`;  

   let a = new MSSQLConnectionObject(mssql_doublettencheckui_config);
   a.build().getBuchungsquelle();
```

I get an error:

```
a.build().getBuchungsquelle();            

TypeError: a.build(...).getBuchungsquelle is not a function
```

why does this not work? Is there an error in how to return this from my functions?

Comment: Well, `build` is asynchronous. You can't call `getBuchungsquelle ` on a Promise. Just use promise chaining.

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt work because your function is `Async`.

You are not actually returning a instance of `MSSQLConnectionObject` but a instance of `Promise<MSSQLConnectionObject>`.

### Async Chaining:

[Check out this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53270222/async-method-chaining) to get a nice example of async chaining!

Comment: thanks, that was the reason... is there a way to avoid async function in a class method, or is there a better approach that resolves the promise somehow in a javascript class method automatically? Or can I just use normal functions without async and just wait for a result to come in? How would you do it?

Comment: You are doing async operations (db queries). So yes it would be wise to keep the functions async and pass the responsibility of resolving to the actual caller. I would avoid chained functions with async operations.

Comment: I probably would have to catch the Promise inside an own class method I guess? And then return or assign the resolved Promise value to a this.someProperty instance inside my class and use that value along? Is something like that correct?

Comment: I added another Stackoverflow post in my answer that shows how to implement async method chaining. Feel free to check it out.

Comment: I dont understand your question right now sorry? @user2774480

Answer (score 2):

> TypeError: a.build(...).getBuchungsquelle is not a function

`build` is an `async` function. When you say `return this`, it creates a function which returns **a promise that resolves to `this`**, not a function that returns `this`.

So to use it you would need to wait for the promise to resolve and **then** call the next function in sequence.

```
a.build().then( x => x.getBuchungsquelle() )
```

Comment: thanks, that was the reason... is there a way to avoid async function in a class method, or is there a better approach that resolves the promise somehow in a javascript class method automatically? Or can I just use normal functions without async and just wait for a result to come in? How would you do it?